# Адаптирование блока через transform: scale

Tags: javascript, reactjs, javascript-events, create-react-app

У меня есть +- след код:
https://codepen.io/ceri911/pen/XQjNaJ

( В моем случае используется react )

И я через `window.addEventListener('resize', this.handleResize.bind(this))`

Запускаю отслеживание изменения экрана.

Примерно вот так:

```
this.state = { 
  windowHeight: (window.innerHeight / 10) * 0.01 
}
<div style={{ transform: `${scale(windowHeight)}`}}>...</div>
```

И это идеально работает для изменений по Y, можно сделать подобное и с X и оно тоже будет отлично работать НО! мне необходимо именно генерировать такое число для  `transform: scale()` которое будет адаптированно для X и Y одновременно. Как можно это осуществить?

Пожалуйста, без JQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение оказалось элементарным:

```
(window.innerHeight / 10) * 0.01 > (window.innerWidth / 9) * 0.01
  ? (window.innerWidth / 9) * 0.01
  : (window.innerHeight / 10) * 0.01
```